# Replacement for pulseaudio-dlna on Ubuntu 20.04 to stream music through DLNA

Tags: pulseaudio, dlna

I would like to start music stream to DLNA receiver from Ubuntu 20.04.

I have created DLNA server already through Settings/Sharing/Media Sharing and I'm able to connect to it and play media files using DLNA receiver (some Denon network audio player), but I'm not able to "trigger" music play from Ubuntu side.

I found, that pulseaudio-dlna package would probably resolve my problem, but it looks like the newest supported Ubuntu version is 17.04. 
What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, as I am using Pop OS 20.04 and need to stream music to a raspberry running Volumio. The solution for me was to download the Debian version from  https://packages.debian.org/sid/all/pulseaudio-dlna/download
Greetings from Chile

Comment: Thanks! It helped, and now I'm able to play music on my dlna receiver.

Comment: Also works for me in Linux Mint 20.1 (based on Ubuntu 20.04). Thanks

Comment: Does not work for me with the current version.

Answer (score 2):

> **UPDATE at 22nd of February 2022**
> Versions 0.6.3 and 0.6.1 installed from [Cygn/pulseaudio-dlna](https://github.com/Cygn/pulseaudio-dlna/releases) work just fine in my computer with following dependencies installed:

```
sudo apt install python3-pychromecast python3-setuptools python3-pip python3-docopt python3-chardet python3-gi python3-dbus python3-docopt python3-requests python3-setproctitle python3-protobuf python3-lxml python3-netifaces python3-zeroconf python3-urllib3 python3-psutil python3-pyroute2 python3-notify2 python3-distutils sox vorbis-tools lame flac opus-tools ffmpeg
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install virtualenv python-dev
```

The newest version 0.6.4 does not work - gives an error:

"pulseaudio-dlna-0.6.4/pulseaudio_dlna/plugins/chromecast/renderer.py", line 191, in from_pychromecast
manufacturer=pychromecast.cast_info.manufacturer,
AttributeError: 'Chromecast' object has no attribute 'cast_info'".

V. 0.6.2 I have not tried.

> **UPDATE at 16th of April 2021.**
> None of the methods described below will work anymore. At the moment, pulseaudio-dlna installed with `sudo apt install pulseaudio-dlna` or with Muon, Synaptic or Discover won't work. The Fedora package might work (I don't know). However this new method will work: [new pulseaudio-dlna with Python-3 libraries included](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/10/how-to-use-pulseaudio-dlna-to-stream.html)

> **EDIT at 27th of October 2020.**
>
> **Debian package did indeed work in Kubuntu 20.10 (I have updated from 20.04) when installed with Gdebi.**
>
> The first time I didn't use Gdebi and the secret may be that Gdebi found the necessary dependencies.

Debian package did not work in Kubuntu 20.04 while trying to render to Google Chromecast Audio, but installing from GitHub and following avodonosov's advice (thanks Anton) in https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna/issues/401 worked!

He (and I) did the installation as Masmu advices in https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna , except that we edited `zeroconf` in `setup.py`. (I didn't try without editing `setup.py` - you might want to try that first).

For you who are amateurs like me, here's additional advice: Installing from GitHub creates a `pulseaudio-dlna` directory in the home directory. After `make` you can execute `pulseaudio-dlna` from `pulseaudio-dlna/bin` folder by clicking the `pulseaudio-dlna` icon (if it is not executable yet, right click it and check the box "executable").

From terminal you can execute it by going to `/home/username/pulseaudio-dlna/bin` and typing:

```
$ ./pulseaudio-dlna
```

Step-by-step direct commands to make `pulseaudio-dlna` work in Kubuntu 20.04 (from avodonosov's answer);
Write/copy following commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python2.7 python-setuptools python-dbus python-docopt python-setproctitle python-gi python-protobuf python-psutil python-concurrent.futures python-chardet python-netifaces python-netaddr python-lxml vorbis-tools sox lame flac faac opus-tools

sudo apt-get install python2-dev

sudo apt-get install virtualenv

git clone https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna.git

cd pulseaudio-dlna/

sudo nano setup.py
```

- nano -command opens setup.py in nano-text editor
- In `setup.py` replace `zeroconf >= 0.17.4` with `zeroconf-py2compat       >=0.19.6`
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to write, ENTER to save and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to leave nano.

```
make
```

After that `pulseaudio-dlna` is executable and working in Kubuntu 20.04. The executable file `pulseaudio-dlna` is in `/home/user/pulseaudio-dlna/bin`.

There's also this https://github.com/masmu/pulseaudio-dlna/pull/404/commits/3a8eed687c2578ee368e826ccfd47045f31128ef that ports pulseaudio-dlna to python 3.8 and is compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 and tested with Google Chromecast

Hint for everybody: Make your life easier and put `pulseaudio-dlna` to autostart list in System Settings, so it automatically starts when you turn your computer on. In KDE Plasma (inc. Kubuntu) go to: **System-Settings/Start-and-Stop/Automatic-Start** and add `pulseaudio-dlna` to programs list. (Of course you already have Yakuake there?).

(You have to install `pulseaudio-dlna` with `make install` if you want to have it in autostart list).

P.S. In my Fedora 32 KDE pulseaudio-dlna works out of the box when installed from  https://copr.fedoraproject.org/coprs/cygn/pulseaudio-dlna/

Comment: With Kubuntu 21.04, it also works out of the box. There is one non-critical error, but the program works. Just installed `pulseaudio-dlna` from repo universe/sound. Should also work on 20.10 since they are basically identical this early.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm on Linux Mint 20.4, version 6.1 from https://github.com/Cygn/pulseaudio-dlna/releases is working

1. Just download and follow this instructions "install local"
   https://github.com/Cygn/pulseaudio-dlna#install-it-local
2. Then run bin/pulseaudio-dlna

There is a latency of about 3 second

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 22.04 (or Linux Mint 21.*), there is a package in the standard repositories, but it doesn't run properly, and the sid unstable package is too new to work with other packages. The best approach seems to be the following.

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dbus python3-docopt python3-requests python3-setproctitle python3-gi python3-notify2 python3-protobuf python3-psutil python3-chardet python3-netifaces python3-pyroute2 python3-netaddr python3-lxml python3-pychromecast vorbis-tools sox lame flac faac opus-tools
```

Install the latest version (0.6.3) of [Cygn's `pulseaudio_dlna`](https://github.com/Cygn/pulseaudio-dlna) which supports `pychromecast` 9.* as a `pip` package and executable script (the released zip is a wheel -- no need to build!):

```
pip3 install https://github.com/Cygn/pulseaudio-dlna/archive/refs/tags/0.6.3.zip
```

This will install the script to .local/bin, and the library and a couple dependencies to .local/lib/python*/site-packages. (If you prefer, you can run as `sudo` and install to the system paths).

Run `pulseaudio-dlna` from Startup Applications, so it is always running. DLNA/Chromecast sinks are now available to stream from the computer (from Sound Settings).