# pulseaudio-dlna permissions

Tags: permissions, pulseaudio

I am running Ubuntu 20.04. I start pulseaudio-dlna with sudo but I still get ERRNO 1 operation not permitted (I also tried without sudo and got the same results). How do I get the pulseaudio-dlna to run correctly?

I did try the suggestions in the recommended post:
[Replacement for pulseaudio-dlna on Ubuntu 20.04 to stream music through DLNA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233123/replacement-for-pulseaudio-dlna-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-stream-music-through-dlna)

I checked out the python3 branch and built it however I still experience the same errors.

```
XXXX@HAL-2017:~/work$ sudo pulseaudio-dlna
[sudo] password for XXXX: 
02-28 08:35:32 pulseaudio_dlna.__main__                       
INFO     Running as root. Starting daemon ...02-28 08:35:33 pulseaudio_dlna.daemon                         INFO     Checking pulseaudio processes ...02-28 08:35:33 pulseaudio_dlna.daemon                         INFO     Adding pulseaudio process (3834)
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.daemon                         INFO     Attaching application to pulseaudio (3834)
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO     Using version: 0.5.2
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO     Binding to *:8080
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO     Loaded device config "/home/XXXX/.local/share/pulseaudio-dlna/devices.json"
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO     Encoder settings:
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvAacEncoder 
available="False" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvFlacEncoder available="False">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvL16Encoder available="False" sample-rate="44100" channels="2">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvMp3Encoder available="False" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvOggEncoder available="False" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvOpusEncoder available="False" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AVConvWavEncoder available="False">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegAacEncoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegFlacEncoder available="True">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegL16Encoder available="True" sample-rate="44100" channels="2">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegMp3Encoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegOggEncoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegOpusEncoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FFMpegWavEncoder available="True">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FaacAacEncoder available="False" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FlacFlacEncoder available="True">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <LameMp3Encoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <NullEncoder available="True">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <OggencOggEncoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <OpusencOpusEncoder available="True" bit-rate="192">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <
SoxL16Encoder available="True" sample-rate="44100" channels="2">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <SoxWavEncoder available="True">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO     Codec settings:
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <AacCodec enabled="True" priority="12" mime_type="audio/aac" backend="generic">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <L16Codec enabled="True" priority="1" mime_type="audio/L16" backend="generic">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <OpusCodec enabled="True" priority="3" mime_type="audio/opus" backend="generic">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <Mp3Codec enabled="True" priority="18" mime_type="audio/mp3" backend="generic">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <FlacCodec enabled="True" priority="9" mime_type="audio/flac" backend="generic">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <WavCodec enabled="True" priority="15" mime_type="audio/wav" backend="generic">
02-28 08:35:35 pulseaudio_dlna.application                    INFO       <OggCodec enabled="True" priority="6" mime_type="audio/ogg" backend="generic">
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 1072, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pulseaudio_dlna/plugins/upnp/ssdp/discover.py", line 126, in _send_discover
sock.sendto(msg, (self.SSDP_ADDRESS, self.SSDP_PORT))
error: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Python 3.8
In 20.04 LTS, the python included in the base system is Python 3.8. Python 2.7 has been moved to universe and is not included by default in any new installs. Read your error messages it wants an old python.

Comment: If you had searched you would have found this question already asked. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233123/replacement-for-pulseaudio-dlna-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-stream-music-through-dlna

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacement for pulseaudio-dlna on Ubuntu 20.04 to stream music through DLNA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233123/replacement-for-pulseaudio-dlna-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-stream-music-through-dlna)

Comment: Hi, I tried the suggestions in the link you provided, they do not fix the issue. I rebuilt using the python3 branch.